# different visibility levels of entity properties based on user role (google endpoints)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

Imagine we have a class User:

```
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String password;
}
```

For a user with admin role, there is no problem to show all properties.

But for a user without admin role, is better to not show some of the properties.

With the annotation @ApiResourceProperty is possible to control the visibility of these properties.

But I'm asking about a good approach to selectively expose (or not) a property, based for example on the role of the user doing the request.

I can use different endpoints for each of the user roles, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach.